# What software can convert all video formats to iPod nano mp4 format?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, ipod

What software can convert all video formats to iPod nano mp4 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Arista Transcoder](http://www.transcoder.org/) [image: install arista]

Arista Transcoder is designed specifically for this sort of thing. It has many presets for devices including the Ipod Nano. You can convert from a file or a number of devices, such as webcams and DVD drives.

[image]

Comment: i already used arista but the results are not suitable to my iphone. plus, the video results have noises with it audio

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind using the command line FFMPEG is the best tool for converting video formats.

Comment: It's a much steeper learning curve but it an save you a lot of time doing multiple videos.

Answer (score 0):

I love [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)! To install handbrake in Ubuntu 14.04 and later run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

It's quite easy and works perfectly. For usage instructions run `man handbrake`

Comment: ok, i try to use handbrake 1st